# Ubuntu 18.04 Beta Install Freezes on Loading screen during install on a AMD Threadripper cpu/mobo

Tags: system-installation, amd-processor, 18.04

I just setup a threadripper 1950x on a asrock taichi motherboard. I burned the ubuntu 18.04 iso to a dvd and booted it up. I'm able to pick the option to "install ubuntu" but it freezes on the loading screen after that. What is the cause of this problem? And how can I fix this install?

Answer (score 1):

**Is the DVD good?**

At the boot menu, select `Check disc for defects`.

It should say  `Check finished:no error found. Press any key to reboot system`.

If it doesn't say that, you will need to burn the DVD again.

**Disable the splash screen to see debug output**

It is often helpful to  disable the splash screen so you can see the kernel debug output.

To do that, as soon as you see the boot menu, press the **E** key. Using the arrow keys move the cursor at the end of the line that says `linux /casper/vmlinux.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---`.

Delete `quiet splash ---` so that the line reads `linux /casper/vmlinux.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper` and then press **F10** to boot.

When the system will hang, look the info and see if you can find any useful tips that could help you (or others) to solve the problem.

**UEFI-related problems**

You could try booting the system in UEFI-CSM mode to rule out problems related to the firmware. Enable UEFI-CSM in your BIOS and in the boot menu of your motherboard choose the entry that doesn't contain `UEFI`.

If you want to edit the boot option to disable the splash screen, as soon as you see this icon [image: man icon] push the spacebar and then select your language. Then, press **F6** and **Escape** and you can now edit the boot option as you did  before.

**Old Radeon card (very unlikely but worth trying)**

If you have an old Radeon card, you might want to use the `nomodeset` option. Edit the boot menu as you did before. Delete `quiet splash ---` and replace it with `nomodeset`.

Comment: The `nomodeset` did the trick for me