# Ubuntu 18.04.1 won't install on Dell Precision M6500

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I have a Dell Precision M6500, it runs 16.04 (64-bit) just fine.

- Hard drive is 500GB
- 8GB RAM
- Intel Core i5 M560 CPU
- Hyperthreading enabled
- SpeedStep enabled
- TPM disabled
- XD support disabled

I swapped hard drives to a known good 320GB drive and tried to install 18.04 - no joy.

It will get to a desktop running on the live DVD, I click on the installation icon, nothing happens.  Tried a second, known good blank 320GB hard drive, same results.

BIOS is current at A10.  Hard drives are physical disks, not SSDs.  Hard drive type in BIOS is AHCI.

I changed no values in BIOS when swapping hard drives. I put the 16.04 hard drive back in the machine, it boots and runs fine.

18.04 Installation DVD has been used to install on other computers without problems and does not appear to be damaged.

I tried an Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 DVD, exact same results.  On a whim, while writing this question, I decided to try a third hard drive, this time a 250GB drive.

Same results, will not launch the installation.

I would appreciate any help and advice you can offer.

I've used Ubuntu since 10.04 and this is the first time I've had a problem installing the OS that I could not solve.

Comment: try booting from usb instead. perhaps that might work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my desktop. Have you tried using a USB to install ubuntu on. This for some reason was what worked it for me. I used rufus to flash the ISO file to the usb and then rebooted the machine.

Comment: The advice to flash the Ubuntu ISO to a USB device sounded good on the surface.  The install still fails, at a different place.  By the way Rufus is a Windows program and no use to me running Ubuntu, but dd works great.  I had hoped my question here would sound at least a minor alarm there was a problem with the Ubuntu live DVD installation.  I guess I need to use a different forum to accomplish that.

Comment: Sorry that i wasn't able to answer your question. Try this thread it may help. [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025346/ubuntu-18-04-beta-install-freezes-on-loading-screen-during-install-on-a-amd-thre)